# Cross join with aggregate greatest value

Tags: mysql, cross-join

I have the following table, let's call it `Segments`:

```
-------------------------------------
| SegmentStart | SegmentEnd | Value |
-------------------------------------
| 1            | 4          | 20    |
| 4            | 8          | 60    |
| 8            | 10         | 20    |
| 10           | 1000000    | 0     |
-------------------------------------
```

I am trying to join this table with itself, to obtain the following result set:

```
-------------------------------------
| SegmentStart | SegmentEnd | Value |
-------------------------------------
| 1            | 4          | 20    |
| 1            | 8          | 60    |
| 1            | 10         | 60    |
| 1            | 1000000    | 60    |
| 4            | 8          | 60    |
| 4            | 10         | 60    |
| 4            | 1000000    | 60    |
| 8            | 10         | 20    |
| 8            | 1000000    | 20    |
| 10           | 1000000    | 0     |
-------------------------------------
```

Basically, I would need to join every row, with every other row that comes after it, then get the `MAX()` of the value between each of the rows joined previously. *Example: if I am joining row 1 with row 3, I would need the `MAX(Value)` from all of these 3 rows.*

What I already done is the following query:

```
SELECT s1.SegmentStart, s2.SegmentEnd, GREATEST(s1.Value, s2.Value) as Value FROM Segments s1 CROSS JOIN Segments s2 ON s1.SegmentStart < s2.SegmentEnd
```

This query creates a similar table to the one desired, but the value fields get mixed up in the following way (I've marked between !! the row that differs):

```
-------------------------------------
| SegmentStart | SegmentEnd | Value |
-------------------------------------
| 1            | 4          | 20    |
| 1            | 8          | 60    |
| 1            | 10         | !20!  |
| 1            | 1000000    | !20!  |
| 4            | 8          | 60    |
| 4            | 10         | 60    |
| 4            | 1000000    | 60    |
| 8            | 10         | 20    |
| 8            | 1000000    | 20    |
| 10           | 1000000    | 0     |
-------------------------------------
```

The problem is with the `GREATEST()` function, because it only compares the two rows that are being joined (start-end 1-4, 8-10), and not the whole interval (in this case, it would be 3 rows, the ones with start-end 1-4, 4-8, 8-10)

How should I modify this query, or what query should I use, to get my desired result?

Additional info, that may help: the rows in the original table, are always ordered based on `SegmentStart`, and there can be no duplicate or missing values. Every interval between `x` and `y` will appear only once in the table, with no overlaps, and no gaps at all.

I am using `Maria DB 10.3.13`.

Comment: You marked `1-10-!20!` as the one having problem but the value after was also different from the top table `1-1000000-20` (top table is `1-1000000-60`).Which one is correct?

Comment: @tcadidot0 yes, you are right, nice catch! The first table, which I said that I want as a result is the correct one.

Comment: @AdamBaranyai , I've tested the answer from fifonik below and it seems to return the results you're expecting ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT
      s1.SegmentStart
    , s2.SegmentEnd
    , MAX(s.Value) as Value 
FROM
    Segments s1
    INNER JOIN Segments s2 ON (
        s2.SegmentEnd > s1.SegmentStart
    )
    INNER JOIN Segments s ON (
            s.SegmentStart >= s1.SegmentStart
        AND s.SegmentEnd <= s2.SegmentEnd
    )
GROUP BY
      s1.SegmentStart
    , s2.SegmentEnd
```